# Right align last word in a line

Tags: text-formatting, columns

…which does *not* exist in every line

Example with `|` marking the maximum length of the line, say 79 characters excluding line-ending(s) and `SPECIAL_WORD` be the last word mentioned in the title:

```
Some words with(some = ! characters, beside ASCII) sdsdds                     |
Some words with(some = ! characters, beside ASCII)   SPECIAL_WORD             |
                                                                              |
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as  SPECIAL_WORD              |
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII) asdb asd                       |
foobar blah SPECIAL_WORD                                                      |
eside ASCII) asdb asd eside ASCII) asdb asd eside ASCII) asdb asd eside ASCII)| asdb asd SPECIAL_WORD
Some words (some = ! characters, be                                           |
Some words (some = ! characters, beSome words (some = ! characters, be SPECIAL|_WORD
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as  SPECIAL_WORD              |
                                                                              |
                                                                              |
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                SPECIAL_WORD|
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                   SPECIAL_W|ORD
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII) asdb asd                       |
                                                                              |
Some words (some SPECIAL_WORD = ! characters, beside ASCII) asdb asd          |
                                                                              |
```

Expected output:

```
Some words with(some = ! characters, beside ASCII) sdsdds                     |
Some words with(some = ! characters, beside ASCII)                SPECIAL_WORD|
                                                                              |
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                SPECIAL_WORD|
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII) asdb asd                       |
foobar blah                                                       SPECIAL_WORD|
eside ASCII) asdb asd eside ASCII) asdb asd eside ASCII) asdb asd eside ASCII)| asdb asd SPECIAL_WORD
Some words (some = ! characters, be                                           |
Some words (some = ! characters, beSome words (some = ! characters, be SPECIAL|_WORD
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                SPECIAL_WORD|
                                                                              |
                                                                              |
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                SPECIAL_WORD|
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                SPECIAL_WORD|
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII) asdb asd                       |
                                                                              |
Some words (some SPECIAL_WORD = ! characters, beside ASCII) asdb asd          |
                                                                              |
```

Quite a mess, isn't it? The rules I try to implement is:

Right align `SPECIAL_WORD` such that

1. the last character of `SPECIAL_WORD` shall sit at column 79, the last character before the line-end character(s)
2. if `SPECIAL_WORD` is followed by any character except the line-ending character(s) that line shall not be touched
3. if the line including `SPECIAL_WORD` is already longer than allowed it shall not be touched
   except when there is enough space to the left of `SPECIAL_WORD`
4. if there is no space between the last character of the line without `SPECIAL_WORD` and the first character of `SPECIAL_WORD` that line shall not be touched
   5- if the length of the line after right aligning `SPECIAL_WORD` is longer than the limit that line shall not be touched
5. `SPECIAL_WORD` may contain more than one word but is to be seen as a single unit
6. `SPECIAL_WORD` consists of ASCII characters only.
7. It is always a single line, there will be no linebreak in `SPECIAL_WORD`

I tried the usual suspects like `col`, `column`, `fmt`, `format`, Bash's `printf`, most of the ideas listed here (`awk`, short shell-script snippets, `sed` and more) but everything was some kind of "close but no cigar". I already reduced the strictness of the rules, so one of the functions/scripts I had to dismiss might work now but there were way too many to remember all of them.

Before I sit down and write a complete parser to do it let me ask here if there is a simpler solution for my problem.

Because of the rightful insistance to make me post what I tried here is what came closest:

```
cat format_test  | perl -e 'my $len;foreach my $line ( <STDIN> ) {$line =~ /^$/ and print $line and next;$line =~ /^(.+?)( *?)(SPECIAL_WORD)?$/;$len = 79-(length($1));  printf("%s%${len}s\n", $1,$3);}'
```

(`cat` is used to make clear that input comes from a pipe)

My deepest apologies to every Perl programmer!

Output of that little abomination:

```
Some words with(some = ! characters, beside ASCII) sdsdds                      
Some words with(some = ! characters, beside ASCII)                 SPECIAL_WORD

Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                 SPECIAL_WORD
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII) asdb asd                        
foobar blah                                                        SPECIAL_WORD
eside ASCII) asdb asd eside ASCII) asdb asd eside ASCII) asdb asd eside ASCII) asdb asdSPECIAL_WORD
Some words (some = ! characters, be                                            
Some words (some = ! characters, beSome words (some = ! characters, beSPECIAL_WORD
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                 SPECIAL_WORD


Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                 SPECIAL_WORD
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII)  as                 SPECIAL_WORD
Some words (some = ! characters, beside ASCII) asdb asd                        

Some words (some SPECIAL_WORD = ! characters, beside ASCII) asdb asd
```

Which works at lines it shouldn't.

Comment: So many rules ... some of them are not that simple to follow. My suggestion, put numbers next to each one, so that if everybody is confused (like me) the can ask directly about it. Also, usually in these cases people add the input **and** the intended output, along with their best solution (as part of the previous research). A bit of context (why do have to do it, who will consume that output) might also be helpful and even offer alternatives to the formatting and/or parsing.

Comment: You can't expect a general-purpose tool to implement exactly this list of rules. awk is the right tool for this, probably - it is almost as flexible as a general-purpose programming language but makes text processing easy. One weakness of awk is its line-orientation, i.e. it's not that easy to process text in the context of other lines than the current line (but definitely feasible), however, a superficial look at your rules seems to indicate that they all operate within a single line.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani well, if it would have been easy I would have done it myself ;-) I changed to a numbered list and added the expected output. Context is just formatting for better readability of a program. There are no alternatives to formatting beside the ones I gave in the rules.

Comment: @berndbausch yes, all in single lines, added a rule to make it clear. No, I don't expect a single program from `texttools` to be able to do it alone, I just hope for someone who had done it before or is an expert in text-formatting.

Comment: I'm curious about what is actually going to consume that strictly formatted output. But well, without any idea on the why I agree with @berndbausch, probably `awk` is a good choice. You can list your rules as the conditions and then do what you have to do inside between the curly brackets. To cope with the *a SPECIAL_WORD might contain more than word* I'd suggest an intermediary file (folding those words into actual SPECIAL_WORD, or something that should not ever appear in the input, process and then unfold).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `perl`, and assuming all characters are single-width:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -lspe '
  BEGIN{$pad = $width - 1 - length $word}
  s/(.*?)\s+\Q$word\E$/sprintf "%-*s %s", $pad, $1, $word/e
' -- -width=79 -word=SPECIAL_WORD < your-file
```

Comment: A nice Perl one-liner, love it! Thanks a lot! I like the new (yes, I'm a bit behind ;-) ) Perl method to "outsource" variables which enables me to easily incorporate it as it is into a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I could write that for you, but not for free :) To get you started, the following implements rule 3:

```
BEGIN { LEN=length(special_word)
        print "special word is", special_word
        print "LEN is", LEN }
$NF == special_word && length($0)<maxlength { print "PROCESSING: " $0; next }
                                            { print }
```

Rule 5 will require some genius, the other rules look rather straightforward to me. *special_word* and *maxlength* are parameters that you have to set when invoking the program. If the program is in *rightalign.awk*, you run it like `awk -f rightalign.awk -v special_word=SPECIAL_WORD -v maxlength=80 inputfile`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see that you posted an answer while I was searching my `~`. Does my edit change anything?

Comment: I consider Perl an abomination in itself and refuse to learn it :) But well done.